# How to create a Java library that packs log4j that all our microservices can then use?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Gradle v7.3.3. (Caveat, I'm no Java programmer, but I understand Gradle.)

Like many companies, we've been hit with the Log4j vulnerabilities. To alleviate this we update all our microservices' `build.gradle` files to the then latest log4j v2.16.0

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api') {
        version {
            strictly '[2.16.0]'
        }
    }
    implementation ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core') {
        version {
            strictly '[2.16.0]'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But then they found vulnerabilities in v2.16.0, so we had to go through the same excercise in updating all or our `build.gradle` files to use `log4j` v2.17.0. I'm reading that we may have to do this yet again?

How can I create a library or a plugin that depends on the latest `log4j` version, that our microservices can then just depend on, like this?

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.mycompany.log4j:company-log4j:2.+')
}
```

So we just then our internal `log4j` library will have this instead?

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api') {
        version {
            strictly '[2.17.0]'
        }
    }
    implementation ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core') {
        version {
            strictly '[2.17.0]'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I created a simple Java library with this code

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package com.company.log4j;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Library {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Library.class.getName());

    public boolean someLibraryMethod() {
        log.info("This is an INFO level log message!");
        log.error("This is an ERROR level log message!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

and it does build, but when I unpack the JAR file, I don't see the `log4j` artifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a gradle [platform project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#java_platform_plugin) to bundle common dependencies such as log4j. The project will produce a maven BOM (bill of material) that can be handled like a usual maven artifact and can easily be [imported with gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import). Other projects simply depend on the platform project, can keep using log4j and will use newer versions once the platform requires a newer version.

In your projects the dependencies to log4j are still declared but without version information. The needed version is provided by means of the platform/BOM.

logging-dependencies/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-platform'
}

dependencies {
  constraints {
    api group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.0'
    api group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.0'
  }
}
```

project-xyz/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform(group: 'my.company.dependencies', name: 'logging-dependencies', version: '2.+')

    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core'
    …
}
```

Comment: Nice. Interestingly, when I do a `gradle init` to create a project, it doesn't give me a `platform` choice, only `1. basic, 2. application, 3. library, 4. Gradle plugin`.

Comment: I'm trying this now, thanks

Comment: For the platform project, how can I add `compile` dependencies/constraints? The example shows `api` and `runtime`, but I need `compile` too since (I tried to use `compile`, but it failed), as you show, the project that will use the platform has the `implementation` dependency, which I need.

Comment: I read the Java Platform blog better, and the `api` is used during compile time. But I get this compile error on the non-platform project `Could not find org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:.
     Required by:
         project :logging-dependencies`, but the artifact is my Nexus repo (I checked).

Comment: It only works if I do add a version information in the implementation configuration for the `log4j` artifacts, e.g., `implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:+'` in the consumer's `build.gradle` file. However, this defeats the purpose of the platform plugin the way you explained it?

Comment: @ChrisF I added basic code for the platform gradle file and updated the project's build file. I think it should work this way. It's important to omit the last colon for the dependencies in the project's gradle file or use the expanded notation with `group` and `name`.